# Regex for Group Links For WhatsApp URL

Tags: php, android, regex

I am using the following regex for validating Group Links For WhatsApp url's.

```
$regex = '/^(https?:\/\/)?chat(?:.whatsapp\.com\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22})$/';//its working for without 'invite'
```

I want the regex to support the following URL formats:

```
https://chat.whatsapp.com/FrTz7HJfmKjAROYZsfDrKQ
https://chat.whatsapp.com/invite/FrTz7HJfmKjAROYZsfDrKQ
```

Comment: Just add `(invite\/)?` in the appropriate position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?chat\.whatsapp\.com\/(?:invite\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22})$
```

`(?:invite\/)?` makes the `invite/` block optional.